# Ideal ring of polynomials in two variables with real coefficients

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $ I= \langle x ^ 4 + y ^ 4 + 2x ^ 2y ^ 2-x ^ 2-y ^ 2 \rangle \subset\mathbb R[X,Y]$. 
I want to determine whether $ I $ is prime or radical.

I know that $I$ is not prime. First, $ \langle x ^ 4 + y ^ 4 + 2x ^ 2y ^ 2-x ^ 2-y ^ 2 \rangle $ is prime if and only if $ x ^ 4 + y ^ 4 + 2x ^ 2y ^ 2-x ^ 2-y ^ 2 = (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2) (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2-1) = f $ is prime. However, letting $ g = x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 $ and $ h = x ^ 2 + y ^ 2-1 $, we have that $ f \mid gh $ but $ f $ does not divide $ g $ or $ h $, and so $ f $ is not prime.

I would like a suggestion as to how to show $I$ is or is not radical.

Comment: I'm not sure it is the best way to do it but you can look for all the prime ideals wich contain $I$. The radical of $I$ is the intersection of them.

Answer (score 0):

there is no other way to test this, such as using Nullstellensatzthere is no other way to test this, such as using Nullstellensatz

Comment: Are you also the person who posted the Question?  This exercise doesn't really seem like invoking *Nullstellensatz* is necessary, but if you wish to answer your own Question in such a fashion, please give the complete details.